# Create a font comparison sheet

Tags: fonts

Is there an application that will take a string, like my company name, and produce a comparison of that string in many different typefaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i don't know what string is here but you can compare your company name in different font style

See these links might be usefull for you..

1. [Type setter](http://www.typetester.org/)
2. [21 Typography and Font Web Apps You Can’t Live Without](http://speckyboy.com/2009/01/12/21-typography-and-font-web-apps-you-cant-live-without/)
3. [Flipping typical](http://flippingtypical.com/) this one is great

Comment: Never considered web based viewers.. Good one. ( +1 )

Comment: @Jack [`string`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=string+datatype) is a programming term for a datatype containing a sequence of characters.

Comment: okay thanks farray, i dont remember exactly, i heard this when i was backbencher in my C language class :D